# Is it possible to restore a deleted Google Analytics site?

Tags: google-analytics

We had an "accident" where someone deleted a Google Analytics site from the dashboard. Is there a way to restore it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try the following from [this guide](http://www.clickinsight.ca/res/google-analytics-resources/can-deleted-google-analytics-profile-be-restored):-

> **Step 1 – Get the following Google Analytics information together:**
>
> - The property ID (UA-xxxxxxx-x) or account number (UA-xxxxxx).
> - The website domain being tracked.
> - The profile name or account name, exactly.
> - The administrator login ID (email address) used to access the Google Analytics account or profile.
> - The name on the administrator login account.
> - When you think the profile or account was deleted.
>
> **Step 2 – Are you a Google Adwords Advertiser?**
>
> - If yes, contact Adwords Help for your country.  Google will restore the profiles or account for free if they can do so.
> - In addition to the info in Step 1, you’ll also asked for your Adwords account number.
> - If no, since we are a Google Analytics Certified Partner, we can put a restoration request in to Google for you.
> - You can contact us Monday to Friday 8 am to 5 pm Eastern Time.  Please use the contact form as we will need the details above.  There is a minimum fee for this service of $250, plus HST if applicable.
> - You must also give Google “Support Access” by Enabling the Support Access Setting.